# What is the data type that is used in typescript to denote a time?

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I need to define a time in typescript so for that I have used the data type as time. But it gives an error. Any suggestion with the data type?

```
Here is the code which I'm getting the error.     
    export class Path {
        public id:number;
        public fromLoaction: string;
        public toLocation: string;
        public cost: number;
        public time: time;

    }
```

Comment: `Date` perhaps? What kind of time anyway?

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Are you looking for time as in `13:45 PM` or as in `12 minutes and 10 seconds`?

Comment: time as in 13:45 PM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Date` stores both times and dates:

```
public time: Date;

this.time = new Date();
console.log(this.time.getHours() + ':' + this.time.getMinutes());
```